# Counter resets after predicate call

Tags: prolog

I am developing a board game and to finalize I'm just missing my win condition.

The winner is supposed to be the 1st player to complete 4 stacks and those stacks are represented by the following board symbols:

```
Player 1 - 's1' , 'S1'
Player 2 - 's2' , 'S2'
```

Therefore, in order to determinate the winner,I have to run through the board (list of lists) and count the number of times the symbols are in the same one. When one of the players reaches 4 stacks completed, then he shall be the winner of the game:

```
checkWin([],_,_).
checkWin([Head|Tail], Counter1, Counter2) :-

        checkStacks(Head, Counter1, Counter2), nl,
        (Counter1 = 4 -> write('Player 1 is the winner!'); true),
        (Counter2 = 4 -> write('Player 2 is the winner!'); true),
        checkWin(Tail,Counter1,Counter2).

checkStacks([],_,_).
checkStacks([Head|Tail], Counter1, Counter2) :-

        Symbol = Head,
        ((Symbol = 's1'; Symbol = 'S1') -> StackCounter1 is Counter1 + 1; StackCounter1 is Counter1),
        ((Symbol = 's2'; Symbol = 'S2') -> StackCounter2 is Counter2 + 1; StackCounter2 is Counter2),

        write('SC1 = '), write(StackCounter1), write('   SC2 = '), write(StackCounter2), nl,

        checkStacks(Tail, StackCounter1, StackCounter2).
```

Although, the code developed does not work as expected. `Counter1` and `Counter2` from `checkWin/3` are meant to be initialized at 0 `?-checkWin([...],0,0).` and increment as matches are found but, instead, it resets to 0 everytime the predicate calls recursion.

Current Output:

```
?- checkWin( [['b0','b0','b0','S1','s1'],
              ['b0','b0','b0','b0','B0'],
              ['b0','b0','b0','s1','S2'],
              ['b0','b0','b0','b0','s2'],
              ['b2','b0','b0','b0','b0']], 0, 0).

SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 1   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 2   SC2 = 0 % SC1 = 2, 2 matches were found for Player1 in the first row

SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0 % SC1 resets to 0 instead of having the previous value(2)
SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0

SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 1   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 1   SC2 = 1

SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 0   SC2 = 1

SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0
yes
% source_info
```

Expected Output:

```
SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 1   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 2   SC2 = 0 

SC1 = 2   SC2 = 0 
SC1 = 2   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 2   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 2   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 2   SC2 = 0

SC1 = 2   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 2   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 2   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 3   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 3   SC2 = 1

SC1 = 3   SC2 = 1
SC1 = 3   SC2 = 1
SC1 = 3   SC2 = 1
SC1 = 3   SC2 = 1
SC1 = 3   SC2 = 2 % - number of matches for each player 

SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0
SC1 = 0   SC2 = 0
yes
% source_info
```

Answer (score 1):

You are 'reversing' the computation flow. Try

```
checkStacks([],0,0).
checkStacks([Head|Tail], Counter1, Counter2) :-

        checkStacks(Tail, StackCounter1, StackCounter2),

        Symbol = Head,
        ((Symbol = 's1'; Symbol = 'S1') -> Counter1 is StackCounter1 + 1; Counter1 is StackCounter1),
        ((Symbol = 's2'; Symbol = 'S2') -> Counter2 is StackCounter2 + 1; Counter2 is StackCounter2).
```

If you want to give Prolog' builtins a try, here is an alternative:

```
checkStacks(L,N1,N2) :-
    findall(t, (member(s1, L) ; member('S1', L)), L1), length(L1,N1)
    findall(t, (member(s2, L) ; member('S2', L)), L2), length(L2,N2).
```

which can be shortened using library(aggregate)

```
checkStacks(L,N1,N2) :-
    aggregate_all(count, (member(s1, L) ; member('S1', L)), N1), 
    aggregate_all(count, (member(s2, L) ; member('S2', L)), N2).
```

and a bit generalized, like

```
occurrences(Symbols, L, N) :-
    aggregate_all(count, (member(S, Symbols), member(S, L)), N).

checkStacks(L,N1,N2) :-
    occurrences([s1,'S1'], L, N1),
    occurrences([s2,'S2'], L, N2).
```

I think checkWin/3 definition doesn't match your description, I would write instead

```
checkWin(Stacks, P) :-
    member(S, Stacks),
    ( occurrences([s1,'S1'], S, 4) -> P = player1
    ; occurrences([s2,'S2'], S, 4) -> P = player2
    ).
```

Comment: I tried implementing your solution, but there might be a problem with `aggregate_all/3`. I keep getting the same error every time I run any of the predicates: `Instantiation error in user:aggregate_all/3
! goal:  aggregate_all(count,user:(member(_197,s1),member(_197,[s1,'S1',b0,'S2'])),0)`

Comment: I tested without the qualification `user:()`

Comment: ugh what am I supposed to do then?

Comment: I tested with SWI-Prolog. Which Prolog are you running ?

Comment: maybe SICStus doesn't support aggregate_all/3. Use the findall/3 snippet then. Sorry for the noise...

Comment: It does support aggregate_all/3, but I guess the "S" in bold`aggregate_all(count, (member(S, Symbols) %this S isn't initialized, member(S, L)), N)` isn't initialized correctly for some reason..

Comment: Anyway, after ajustments the code is working correctly. THanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to CapelliC, and after adjusting the predicates provided, I finally got to a solution to my problem. Here's how it looks:

```
occurrences(Symbol, L, N) :-
        aggregate_all(count, member(Symbol, L), N).

checkWin([], C1, C2) :- write('Player 1 Counter = '), write(C1), nl, 
                        write('Player 2 Counter = '), write(C2), nl.
checkWin([Head|Tail], C1, C2) :-

        occurrences('s1', Head, N),
        occurrences('S1', Head, N1),
        occurrences('s2', Head, N2),
        occurrences('S2', Head, N3),

        D1 is N + N1 + C1, D2 is N2 + N3 + C2,
        checkWin(Tail, D1, D2).
```